# Why can't I send a mail to a @thinc.local mail address?

Tags: dns

I'm training for a certification in computer security and trying to perform a client side attack by sending a payload to an mail account. Problem: when I send the email with my casual gmail address I have a message back with this error message:

> DNS Error: 4910698 DNS type 'mx' lookup of thinc.local responded with
>   code NXDOMAIN Domain name not found: thinc.local

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is no MX entry for thinc.local and semdmail cannot determine which host receives mail for that domain. Seeing that thinc.local is a zeroconf/bonjour domain you would need to change the sendmail configuration on your local machine to say that it handles email for thinc.local. That is normally done in /etc/mail/local-host-names

Comment: Thanks for your help, but there is no /etc/mail/loca-host-names file in my Kali Machine

Comment: I am not sure which mail daemon kali linux uses. If it uses sendmail then there will be a sendmail.mc file in the same folder (/etc/mail) Edit it and add a line that reads LOCAL_DOMAIN(`thinc.local')dnl Then run make in the same folder to create a new sendmail.cf program. You will then need to restart the sendmail daemon. If you have postfix installed, instead of sendmail, then someone else would have to answer the question as I am unfamiliar with postfix.

Comment: There is no sendmail.mc in Kali Rolling

Comment: Maybe you do not have a mail daemon installed at all or Kali is using postfix. In either case I cannot help you and you would need to search google for information o. adding a local domain is postfix or installing sendmail in kali.

Comment: But can't I tell gmail to use mail.thinc.local (which I just found the IP address) as a DNS mx server ?

Comment: You never mentioned that you were using gmail to send email. In that case you will never get thinc.local to work as gmail uses google's DNS servers and no MX record can exist for thinc.local in the public internet. You would need to use thunderbird or mutt and point it to you local smtp server which is configured to accept email for thinc.local

Comment: Ok, but can I use sendmail also ? (I prefer not to pay to have a new address on Thunderbird)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44624/discussion-between-addon-and-peter-skarpetis).

Comment: Sorry, can't help you any further.  You should write up a new question with more details of wha you are trying to do and what you have done so far, and some one will help you.